# Understanding the Twitter rate limit

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using `Tweepy` to write a function that will return all the followers for a large Twitter account and write them to a file. I've been reading about the Twitter rate limit but it still isn't quite making sense. The documentation says "15 calls every 15 minutes, and 180 calls every 15 minutes." However, when I run my code without the sleep function I manage to get around 280 names before twitter cuts me off. So how many calls am I actually making here? My code is as follows:

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("...", "...")
auth.set_access_token("...", "...")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

f = open('output.txt', 'w')
timecount = 0
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="NAME").items():
    timecount = timecount + 1
    if timecount == 200:    
        print "HOLD ON A SECOND!!!"
        #print api.rate_limit_status()
        time.sleep(60*15)
        timecount = 0   
    data = user.screen_name 
    print user.screen_name  
    print >> f, data   
f.close()
```

Right now it's waiting 15 minutes between every 280 names it gets which seems to be working. Obviously, I want this to run as efficiently as possible. Can anyone help me understand how many calls I'm making how long I should be waiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maths is pretty simple in this case, You are actually making 14 requests before twitter cuts you off, But you are able to fetch 280 names because `tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="NAME")` is a single request which returns 20 values at a time, this means that you fetch 20 values for on a single request, And as you mentioned that you were able to fetch 280 names, which is not surprising as **280/20 = 14** So actually you made only 14 requests and you are just iterating over the 280 values to print out the names, etc. Kindly refer to the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html) for further details.

Comment: So in that case, I should be able to safely pull 260 or 280 names followed by 15 minutes of waiting to avoid having the rate limiter cut me off?

Comment: You can do it in even more efficient way by using `api.followers()` method which returns 100 values for a single request. Consider the documentation for more info, As far as sleeping time is concerned , you should hibernate for 15 mins after reaching the rate limit. and repeat this sleeping and fetching behaviour as long as you want, safely, without any adverse effects as far as I know.

Comment: Turns out that the Tweepy documentation is incorrect. Each request defaults to 20 values, not 100. That being said...you can change the request size to 200 which makes all the difference in the world. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would add this in comments but I cannot due reputation and stuffs. I had the same issue a while ago. You can actually fetch up to 5000 usernames per request meaning that you can get 75000 followers every 15 min. Just increase the count to 5000. The call uses followers/list call. Here is the [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids).